# How to disable a button in a remote view?

Tags: android

I can make it invisible using the code below, but can't disable it.

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonToDisable, View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setEnabled()` is a `@RemotableViewMethod`, at least on [the now-current `master` branch of the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java). Hence, you should be able to [use `setBoolean()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setBoolean(int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)):

```
contentView.setBoolean(R.id.buttonToDisable, "setEnabled", false);
```

Comment: I couldn't use it on API 16, but I accept it as the answer, because it seems correct.

Comment: @TamásBolvári: Yes, sometimes, they add that annotation to methods which lacked it before. Your only other option is to have two layout resources, one with the button enabled and one with the button disabled.

Comment: nope -- that will give you "Button can't use method with RemoteViews: setEnabled(boolean)"

Comment: @tom: What version of Android did you try it on? I do not know when they added this, but it should be available on Android 7.0+ at minimum.

Comment: @CommonsWare Android 6.0.1.  From gradle: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
        applicationId "org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 33
        versionName "3.3"

Comment: @tom: `setEnabled()` has had the `@RemotableViewMethod` annotation since [at least the end of 2013](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d863a10b2870ca27f631b2ec69f3e13faed1d02a/core/java/android/view/View.java#L6238-L6239). So, I cannot explain your results, but I am sorry that it is not working for you.

Comment: I just tested and confirmed this works on Android 7.1.1 and 4.1.2 for an `ImageButton`.

Comment: This also worked for an `ImageButton` on Android 4.0.2.

Comment: Don't work with TextView on Android 4.4.2 (API 19) and 4.2.2 (API 17)

Comment: @almisoft: What would it mean to disable a `TextView`?

Comment: The textColor is gray. It is easier than change the color manually, if you use multiple color themes.

Answer (score 0):

no dice trying to update remote view ind. components e.g.:

```
Button can't use method with RemoteViews: setEnabled(boolean)
```

try switching out the layout

```
 if(((WzBlockWordTheme) wzTheme).mForeign) {
           newRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.german_clock_wordzoo_vocabr);
        }
        else {
           newRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.german_clock_wordzoo_vocabr_wait);
        }
```